# Stylization of radiobuttons in groups with CSS and jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have an form with many groups of radiobuttons like this:

```
<form blah-blah-blah>
    <input type="radio" id="id1_1" name="nam1" value="" class="rad">
      <label for="id1_1" class="kf">label1_1</label>
    <input type="radio" id="id1_2" name="nam1" value="" class="rad">
      <label for="id1_2" class="kf">label1_2</label>
    <input type="radio" id="id1_3" name="nam1" value="" class="rad">
      <label for="id1_3" class="kf">label1_3</label>
    <input type="radio" id="id2_1" name="nam2" value="" class="rad">
      <label for="id2_1" class="kf">label2_1</label>
    <input type="radio" id="id2_2" name="nam2" value="" class="rad">
      <label for="id2_2" class="kf">label2_2</label>
    <input type="radio" id="id2_3" name="nam2" value="" class="rad">
      <label for="id2_3" class="kf">label2_3</label>
</form>
```

I use the CSS to change style of radios.

```
.rad {display:none;}
.kf {padding:2px; background-color:#eaeaea; border:1px solid #dadada; cursor:pointer;}
.kf:hover, .sel {background-color:#3a608e; color:#fff;}
```

Finaly, i use the jQuery to get it works, but it does not.
Radio changes by click on label.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".rad").change(function(){
            if($(this).is(':checked')){      
                $(this).next("label").addClass("sel");
            }else{
                $(this).next("label").removeClass("sel");
            };
        });
    });
```

Labels must change his color if radio is checked. If radio lost 'checked' state label must change color to 'unselected'.

What's wrong (don't forget about several groups of radios)?

EDIT UPDATE:
I've combined both answers to most elegant solution =)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".rad").change(function(){
        var chk_name = $(this).attr("name");
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            $(this).parents().find('input[name="'+chk_name+'"]').each(function(){
                $(this).next('label').removeClass('sel');
            });
            $(this).next("label").addClass("sel");
        };
    });
});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".kf").click(function() {
        var chk = $(this).prev("input");
        var chk_name = $(chk).attr("name");
        if (!$(chk).is(':checked')) {
            $(this).parent().find('input[name="' + chk_name + '"]').each(function () {
                $(this).removeAttr("checked");
                $(this).next('label').removeClass('sel');
            });
            $(chk).attr("checked", "checked");
            $(this).addClass('sel');
        } else {
            $(chk).removeAttr("checked");
            $(this).removeClass('sel');
        }
    });
});
```

A working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7PTep/12/)

Comment: Nope. Just one item can be selected in a group of radios. i.e. two elements on this form.

Comment: Check my example again. Greatings!

Comment: I've combined both answers to most elegant solution =)

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".rad").change(function(){
            var chk_name = $(this).attr("name");
            if($(this).is(':checked')){
                $(this).parents().find('input[name="'+chk_name+'"]').each(function(){
                    $(this).next('label').removeClass('sel');
                });
                $(this).next("label").addClass("sel");
            };
        });
    });

Answer (score 1):

following should work

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 var $chk=null;
    $(".rad").change(function(e){
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            if($chk) $chk.next("label").removeClass("sel");
            $(this).next("label").addClass("sel");
            $chk=$(this);
        }else{
            $(this).next("label").removeClass("sel");
        };
    });
});​
```

Comment: Not work. Yes, now labels lost 'selected' state, but ALL labels, not just in current group of radio. I mean.. just one label on the entire form may be selected in your example.

Comment: I've combined both answers to most elegant solution =)

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".rad").change(function(){
            var chk_name = $(this).attr("name");
            if($(this).is(':checked')){
                $(this).parents().find('input[name="'+chk_name+'"]').each(function(){
                    $(this).next('label').removeClass('sel');
                });
                $(this).next("label").addClass("sel");
            };
        });
    });